# PHP date - String to Timestamp

Tags: php, date

I am trying to parse date strings without having to manipulate strings and expect a given format.

I want my user to be able to enter `January 2, 2011` or `1-2-11`, and still end up with `2011-01-02 12:00:00` to save in a database.

Currently, I have this in place:

```
$post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(stripslashes($_POST['post_date'])));
```

But it seems strtotime is returning 0, because the datetime ends up as `1969-12-31 17:00:00`

What do I need to change?

---

UPDATE

From php.net:

(PHP 4, PHP 5)

strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp.

..I guess not!

---

I am not trying to strtotime( an array:

```
if(isset($_POST['post_date'])){
                foreach($_POST['post_date'] as $id => $post_date){
                    print $post_date.'<br />';
                    if(strlen(trim($post_date)) && $post_date !== 'Date posted'){
                        $update_data[$id]['post_date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(stripslashes($post_date)));
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

Got it working with:

```
if(isset($_POST['post_date'])){
                foreach($_POST['post_date'] as $id => $post_date){
                    print $post_date.'<br />';
                    if(strlen(trim($post_date)) && $post_date !== 'Date posted'){
                        $post_date = str_replace(',', '', $post_date);
                        $post_date = str_replace('-', '/', $post_date);
                        $update_data[$id]['post_date'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(stripslashes($post_date)));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks to multiple contributors. I remove commas and replace hyphens with forward slashes.

Comment: What's $_POST['post_date'] currently?

Comment: $_POST['post_date'] is actually an array (updating multiple records), but an example value would be 'December 31, 2012'

Comment: Agree with genesis. I just tested it with PHP5.3 and it worked fine. One thing to keep in mind, though, is that strtotime will often read #-#-# as Year-Month-Date. If you want different behavior you might need to parse it more thoroughly first.

Comment: You can't use `strtotime()` on an array. Are you sure you're passing a string to it, not an array?

Comment: If you do `echo strtotime( 'December 31, 2012' );`, is the result `0`?

Comment: Can you do `echo $_POST['post_date']` just above that line and tell us what it outputs? It works fine for me given your example inputs.

Comment: +1 to Dano; As stated in my answer, and like Dano, I tested it on my system as well and `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('January 2, 2011'))` gives `2011-01-02` as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments the OP said :

> $_POST['post_date'] is actually an array (updating multiple records),
>   but an example value would be 'December 31, 2012'

You cannot pass a comma in the `strtotime` arguments alongside time, doing so would always return a `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. You have to remove the user generated comma.

```
$post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(stripslashes("1 January 1927 17:59")));
echo $post_date; //1927-01-01 17:59:00
```

Comment: Commas can confuse strtotime(), but I don't think it will always break it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I just tested strtotime() with `January 2, 2011` and it worked fine. Maybe different versions, ini, systems, etc.

Comment: @Dano See http://codepad.org/F9c2DHMh  and http://codepad.org/R4kaWuWo 
In both cases they both break `strtotime`. I think this answer fits perfectly with this question and doesn't warrant a downvote. Yes it could boil down to different versions. I suggest he just removes the comma and run it.

Comment: @Mob the comma only breaks when you add the time to the date with comma. The date with comma but without hour and seconds gives expected results. [codepad.org/qgJIJSaw](http://codepad.org/qgJIJSaw)

Comment: @ghbarratt Ok. Thanks. I did not know.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to be concerned with your input, but here's an idea.

```
foreach($_POST['input'] as $userDate) {
    // strtotime() will assume m/d/y or y-m-d depending on if '-' of '/' is used.
    $userDate = str_replace('-', '/', $userDate);
    $post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(stripslashes($userDate)));
}
```

Comment: ++ For input concerns. That's the major thing here.

Comment: Unfortunately, strtotime will not assume d-m-y, but will actually assume y-m-d. [codepad.org/vbZ0tObH](http://codepad.org/vbZ0tObH)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3.3+ (and perhaps older versions)

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('January 2, 2011'))
```

(notice the comma IS there) will give you `2011-01-02`

However, when you add hour and minute to the end of that date phrase, strtotime DOES return 0.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('January 2, 2011 14:30'))
```

Unfortunately gives you `1970-01-01 00:00:00`
Notice: http://codepad.org/qgJIJSaw

Consider removing the comma:

```
$date = str_replace(',', '', $date);
```

Also, strtotime will convert '1-2-11' to 2001-02-11 (February 11th 2001), so you will probably need to rearrange the numbers if they fit the pattern, using something like:

```
 $date = preg_replace('#^([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{1,2})-([\d]{2,4})$#', '$3-$1-$2', $date);
```